# I need to identify $G/H$ upto isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

$\varphi:G=(\mathbb{C}^*,.)\to (\mathbb{C}^*,.)$ given by $\varphi(z)=z^4$

clearly Ker$\varphi=H=\{z:z^4=1\}=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$

I need to identify $G/H$ upto isomorphism.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is surjective. It follows from one of the isomorphism theorems that its codomain is isomorphic to the quotient of its domain by its kernel.

Comment: $G/H\cong\mathbb{C}^*$ ..................